# Ruby -c option actual task

Tags: ruby, indentation

I have a little piece of Ruby code, the interpreter suddenly started to complain . When I run the program I get:

```
:85: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'while' at 75
```

But i cant see any mismatched while/end
If then i check it with the c option i get:

```
ruby -c Db_manager.rb
Syntax OK
```

So what is `-c` actually doing here? Is it actually checking the indentation?
Shall I refresh something?

```
53   def dump_mysql
54    period=period
55    @dump=File.new("#{@tmp_dir}dump.txt","w")
56    query=@db_standard_hash["database_dump_query"]
57    result=@connection.query(query)
58    final=""
59    while run = result.fetch_hash do
60      arr=run.values
61       arr.each do |value|
62        value = "NULL" if value.nil?
63        final << value
64        final << "\t"
65      end
66        final=final.chop
67        final << "\n"
68        @dump.write(final)
69      final = ""
70    end
71    @dump_users=File.new("#{@tmp_dir}dump_second.txt","w")
72    query=@db_standard_hash["users_query"]
73    result=@connection.query(query)
74     final = ""
75     while local = result.fetch_hash do
76      usr_arr=local.values
77       usr_arr.each do |value|
78        final << value
79        final << "\t"
80       end
81        final=final.chop
82        final << "\n"
83        @dump_users.write(final)
84      final = ""
85    end
86   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you run your program you are using the option `-w` to turn warnings on, but you omit it when checking the syntax with the `-c` options. I've saved your code in a file named `foo.rb`:

```
$ ruby -c foo.rb
Syntax OK

$ ruby -c -w foo.rb
foo.rb:33: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'while' at 23
Syntax OK
```

It is just informing you that the `end` keyword corresponding to the `while` at line 23 (75 in your example) is non consistently indented, it is indeed indented by only one space.

Comment: Thx, i did not know the warnings of Ruby's interpreter are so accurate and strict.